# Saxon-PE 9.5.1.4 Error "Local variable $v has not been allocated a stack frame slot"

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am using Saxon-PE 9.5.1.4 to transform some documents and I am getting the following error printed:

```
Local variable $x has not been allocated a stack frame slot
```

Unfortunately I can't easily access the stylesheet which is doing the transformation or a stack trace, just this error.

What I can say, is that this transform worked fine with Saxon-HE 9.4.x

Before I spend hours trying to dig down and create an xsl that reproduces this, I am hoping someone might have seen this before, or perhaps it is a known bug?

Thanks

Comment: There is https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2011 "failure to allocate stack frame slot", I am not able to tell whether that is the same as your bug. You might want to raise your issue on that Saxon support site, then they can tell you whether it is the same issue or a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a run-time error, but it arises as a symptom of a problem occurring (usually) at compile time during the optimization phase (you can test this by running with -opt:0 to see if this makes the problem go away). The fact that other bugs exhibit the same symptom doesn't mean it's he same bug (like a NullPointerException, it can have many different underlying causes). Generally, because it happens during optimization, it's very sensitive to minor changes in the source code, so it's best to send us the original source and let us do the trimming down. If you can't get hold of the source, then sorry, there's little we can do to help.

Sorry, this isn't really an answer according to SO rules, but it's too long to go in a comment.

The preferred way to report Saxon problems is at saxonica.plan.io. Then we can track them to a resolution.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Now that I know there is a way for you to track down the exact issue I will take the time to create a stylesheet which reproduces this consistently. It may take me a few days but when ready I will submit it to saxonica. Thanks!

Comment: So it turns out this problem was caused by having a duplicate global variable declaration.

Comment: No, the problem was caused by a bug in Saxon that only revealed itself when you had a duplicate global variable declaration. Please help us to improve the quality of the product by submitting bug reports when you hit problems like this.